# Syntax for options_from_collections_for_select in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

I'm trying to add a class to the select drop down populated using options_from_collection_for_select

Here's the snippet I'm working with:

```
<%= select_tag "instructor", options_from_collection_for_select(@instructors, "id", "full_name"), :include_blank => true %>
```

Where do html_options go in this instance?

Desired result:

```
<select id="example_select" name="example_select" class="example_class">
    <option value></option>
    <option value="1">Example option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Example option 2</option>
</select>
```

I've tried to follow syntax for options_for_select and have only found questions relating to that tag specifically; it doesn't work as I'd expect.

**Any advice for this question, and for select tag templating questions like this in general would be appreciated.**

Comment: perhaps this will help:  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is actually simple:

```
<%= select_tag "instructor", options_from_collection_for_select(@instructors, "id", "full_name"), :include_blank => true, :class => "example_class" %>
```

Will produce:

```
<select id="example_select" name="example_select" class="example_class">
    <option value></option>
    <option value="1">Example option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Example option 2</option>
</select>
```

Thanks [Jesse Goodfellow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1908882/jesse-goodfellow)

Reference: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select